# What's "higher level" than type theory as far as implementing a different kind of proof assistant goes?

Tags: category-theory, algorithms, computer-science, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I'm in the process of designing a better "logic framework" for BananaCats.   Why do I seem limited to Type Theory (which is extremely "low level" for lack of better description).  I don't care about most of the stuff talked about in the various books on type theory.  All I care about is Category Theory (mostly) and various proofs in *those* books.  What are the drawbacks to just implementing a C++ class called "Category", "Object", "Arrow", "Functor", and so on...  Essentially implement everything needed to do every proof in a given textbook?

As you can tell I'm not a fan of taking the bare bones basics and creating another Coq.  It seems like we've done all we can do there.  If I need natural numbers, say I'll just implement an "Integer" class, for example.  If I want to prove Yoneda, I'd need composition, taking elements, natural maps, etc., each concept hard-coded as much as is reasonable.

Below is a 90% visual proof of (one part of) Yoneda's Lemma, that is in a "final stage" of the proof.  For example, a reader of the proof might have to go through several diagram changes in a slide show before arriving at this point.

[image: 90% Visual Proof of Yoneda's Lemma (a part thereof)]

There is a note in the picture, which demonstrates a text accompaniment to the drawing, but as you might have guessed, if I can somehow encode this visually using CD's, I will.

One feature that needs to be hard-coded is if the user takes an element of a set, and there are set-like map arrows (arrows that maybe are subclasses of C++ class type SetMap, or "is a set map" is one of their properties, or however it should be implemented); then, the result of mapping that element to elements in the codomain sets (which might be several in a diagram), is auto-populated, with the correct LaTeX markup in labels which straddle the respective codomain nodes.  That was an example of what I mean.

I hope I'm clear enough on this.  So, without re-inventing the wheel, how should one proceed, if they definitely want to avoid such low-levelness as described in the various type theories?

Comment: I cannot understand what you are asking exactly. Are you looking to ways on how to define categories, functors, etc in a programming language as C++? or what else?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa you know how Coq is implemented "exactly like" a certain type theory?  Was wondering if there was a strictly higher-level theory that doesn't require tedious rudiments to be defined.  Alternatively, yes, suggestions on how to code it using C++ classes in an OOP way would be helpful and would also be a valid answer.  I've already run into problems with cyclic header dependency since Variable subclasses Expression, yet we need to get the expression variables.  Solved that with a global function placed in variables.h.

Comment: In one sense, you're probably out of luck - there is a formal sense in which category theory is "exactly like" type theory: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relation+between+type+theory+and+category+theory

Comment: This is not an answer, but I suspect that C++ type system is not strong enough to allow to do full category theory.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa how can that be the case if it's possible that OCAML was written in C++ (say) and Coq is written in OCAML?

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamondShine oh I see what you mean. Allow me rephrase just because you could theoretically do something that doesn't mean that could be done in the space of post. So it seems really un reasonable to ask something like that here. Though I maybe wrong, that's why I said "I suspect" and not "it is certainly impossible".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no higher level view other than perhaps the Type Theory - Category Theory correspondence mentioned in the comments.

As a solution to this problem, I recommend learning the Coq proof assistant langauge called Gallina.  With knowledge of it comes knowledge of type theory itself.

I remcommend Coq over Isabelle for a programmer, as naturally later you may wish to extend Coq using the OCaml API or modifying Coq's open source code itself.  Isabelle doesn't seem to be as modifiable.

Comment: Isabelle is a very different thing than Coq, and the modifiability of the source code is likely very low on most user's priorities. Isabelle itself is a framework for defining logical systems, hence things like Isabelle/ZF and Isabelle/HOL, often the latter is what is intended. Isabelle/HOL is not a dependent type theory and doesn't work via Curry-Howard. That is, in Isabelle/HOL you have a logic that talks *about* typed lambda terms and you produce proofs in the traditional sense rather than by exhibiting terms as in Coq. (Indeed, every type is inhabited in Isabelle/HOL axiomatically.)